# The Identity operator does not act correctly on adjoint operators

Tags: python, operators, sympy

I define an abstract operator A and the identity operator I. As expected, `A*I = I*A =*A`. However, if I consider the adjoint of A it seems that the identity operator does not act properly, i.e. `Dagger(A)*I` is not simplified to `Dagger(A)` (see code below).
How can I define an identity operator which acts on both operators and on their adjoints?

```
from sympy.physics.quantum.dagger import Dagger
from sympy.physics.quantum.operator import Operator
from sympy.physics.quantum import IdentityOperator
A = Operators('A')
Identity = IdentityOperator()
A * Identity #This gives A, correctly
B = Dagger(A)
B * Identity #This returns A^\dagger I . so it does not remove the identity operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `qapply` to canonicalise the result:

```
In [9]: from sympy.physics.quantum import qapply                                                                                               

In [10]: B*Identity                                                                                                                            
Out[10]: 
 †  
A ⋅I

In [11]: qapply(B*Identity)                                                                                                                    
Out[11]: 
 †
A
```